# How to get User Profile Property settings changed value?

Tags: user-profile-property

I would like to know how to get the Property Privacy settings when the user changed from "MY Manager" to "My colleague" in edit profile page ?

I am able to get the Default privacy value, but i want user-specific Privacy settings value for specific property.. ? How can i achieve this ?

Comment: could you say what approach you have in mind (programmatically - event handling, powershell,etc.) ?

Answer (score 2):

I got this using SharePoint API.  Find the following code.

```
        string privacyvalue = string.Empty;
        SPUser AdminUser = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"];
        var superToken = AdminUser.UserToken;
        HttpContext con = HttpContext.Current;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, superToken))
            {
                SPServiceContext context1 = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                HttpContext.Current = null;
                UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(context1, false);
                this.userProfile = upm.GetUserProfile(this.UserAccount);
                Privacy privacy = this.userProfile[PropertyName].Privacy;
                privacyvalue = privacy.ToString();
             }  
         });
       HttpContext.Current = con;
```

Comment: to get the systemaccount you should just use SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount and also if you want to update or commit the userprofile you should use                         System.Security.PermissionSet ps = new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
ps.Assert();

Comment: Can you please mark this as your answer (to put the question in correct state)? :)